# c# + Find the pdf file property "Can be opened by"

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.pdf

I am opening pdf  files using Aspose library and I am trying to read the property displayed in the “Can be opened by” when using Adobe Acrobat Reader.

[image]

Can someone help me and let me know which property has that information displayed under the “Can be opened by”?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe it's a simply weird representation of [pdf version](https://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/version). Acrobat 6.0 means PDF version 1.5. Nothing else.

Comment: I think you should inquire with Aspose's support page instead. [Aspose Support](https://forum.aspose.com/)

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply .

Comment: IMHO: this is not a document property. This is a message related to the subset of security properties. For example, an unencrypted document can be opened by any version of Adobe Acrobat, but if you use encryption with Password Security and 128 AES Encryption, then your document Can be Opened by Adobe Acrobat 7.0 or higher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SergioKastro,

You can retrieve and set the properties of the PDF document as well as XMP properties with DocumentInfo and Metadata member of the Document class. 
**C#**

```
// Open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document(dataDir + "GetFileInfo.pdf");
// Get document information
DocumentInfo docInfo = pdfDocument.Info;
// Show document information
Console.WriteLine("Author: {0}", docInfo.Author);
Console.WriteLine("Creation Date: {0}", docInfo.CreationDate);
Console.WriteLine("Keywords: {0}", docInfo.Keywords);
Console.WriteLine("Modify Date: {0}", docInfo.ModDate);
Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", docInfo.Subject);
Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", docInfo.Title);
Facades.PdfFileInfo fileInfo = new Facades.PdfFileInfo(pdfDocument);
fileInfo.GetPdfVersion();
```

The code examples are documented in this help topic: [PDF File Metadata](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/PDF+File+Metadata)